# Simple Java Recursion Method

Tags: java

What is the wrong of this code? need help.

```
public class TailRrecursion {

    public static void tail(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(i + "");
            tail(i - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The indentation is very wrong.

Comment: First, I am pretty sure method need `{ }`to work

Comment: Alas! If you would have formatted it you will know you are missing `{` for function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you are missing curly `{` braces

see

```
public class Tail-recursion{
   public static void tail(int i) {
      if(i>0){
        System.out.print (i +"");
        tail(i-1);
      }
   }   
}  // and here
```

Comment: I didn't expect someone like you to add this as an answer. It should be closed as this is a typo problem

Comment: If he just missed one curly, I would say a `typo` but two just shows lack of basic understanding - maybe should have an option to close for that?

Comment: IMHO, `this is a problem that can no longer be reproduced`, that's why I thought of closing it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thankz bro